# JaxB marshalling into child's namespace?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

I'm currently attempting to marshall an object in to xml but upon the marshalling the namespaces are ending up too far down and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the ValuationIn referencing ValuationDetails inside of the valuation.xsd:

```
    <xs:complexType name="ValuationIn">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element xmlns:q1="httpAddress/common" minOccurs="0" name="ValuationIdentifier" nillable="true" type="q1:ValuationIdentifier">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element xmlns:q2="httpAddress/common" minOccurs="0" name="ValuationDetails" nillable="true" type="q2:ValuationDetails">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

and here is the ValuationDetails element within the common schema:

```
    <xs:element name="ValuationDetails" nillable="true" type="tns:ValuationDetails"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Policy">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PolicyEffectiveDate" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PolicyRenewalDate" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EstimateExpirationDate" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CurrentCoverage" nillable="true" type="xs:int">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccountNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttachmentCount" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RecordType" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DataSource" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Policy" nillable="true" type="tns:Policy"/>
```

and here is the element within the valuationService schema:

```
<xs:element name="GetFastTrackURL">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element xmlns:q35="httpAddress/valuation"
                minOccurs="0" name="FastTrackRequest" nillable="true"
                type="q35:FastTrackRequest" />
            <xs:element xmlns:q36="httpAddress/valuation"
                minOccurs="0" name="Valuation" nillable="true" type="q36:ValuationIn" />
            <xs:element xmlns:q37="httpAddress/valuation"
                minOccurs="0" name="SupplementalDataRequest" nillable="true"
                type="q37:SupplementalDataRequest" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I break it down and compare it to the working hardcoded XML that we have on the project I can see that the namespaces are off.  Comparing a small subsection of the xml shows the hardcoded on top and the generated on the bottom.

Hardcoded:

```
<val:Valuation>
    <val1:ValuationDetails>
        <com:PropertyAddress>
            <com:Address1>Address</com:Address1>
            <com:City>City</com:City>
            <com:StateProvince>MI</com:StateProvince>
            <com:ZipPostalCode>Zip</com:ZipPostalCode>
        </com:PropertyAddress>
        <com:Building>
            <com:MainHome>
                <com:YearBuilt>1979</com:YearBuilt>
                <com:LivingArea>2000</com:LivingArea>
            </com:MainHome>
        </com:Building>
    </val1:ValuationDetails>
</val:Valuation>
```

Generated:

```
<val1:ValuationIn>
    <com:ValuationDetails>
        <com:PropertyAddress>
            <com:Address1>Address</com:Address1>
            <com:City>City</com:City>
            <com:StateProvince>MI</com:StateProvince>
            <com:ZipPostalCode>Zip</com:ZipPostalCode>
        </com:PropertyAddress>
        <com:Building>
            <com:MainHome>
                <com:YearBuilt>1979</com:YearBuilt>
                <com:LivingArea>2000</com:LivingArea>
            </com:MainHome>
        </com:Building>
    </com:ValuationDetails>
</val1:ValuationIn>
```

the subsection of the XML that I included is the q36 in the schema and the namespaces they refer to in the hardcoded vs generated is that in the hardcoded xml the xmlns=valuationService while in the generated xmlns=valuation (valuation and valuationservice being two of the different schemas).

Here is the import at the top of the ValuationService.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="httpAddress/valuationservice">
    <xs:import namespace="httpAddress/valuation" schemaLocation="valuation.xsd" />
    <xs:import namespace="httpAddress/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
```

I know that was a lot to write for something that will probably be fairly simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out why my marshalled xml is referring to a different namespace than it is in the main schema.

Comment: You shoudl include jaxb beans instead of the marshaller as the problem will be related to the mappings. Attached xml suggest that the problem is in valuationDetails being in wrong namespace com instead of val?. The encloed xsd schema does not describe the valuatioDetails element so it is hard to say which document is correct (the hardcoded or the generated), especially without the root of the document where the namespace preficex are resolved. Please add those missing bits.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the messiness, the problem is that valuationDetails, when marshalled, is referring to the incorrect namespace and I can't figure out how to have it set to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the jaxb bean I can only guess. 
But, 
in your xsd schema the valuationinfo is in httpAddress/common namespace, so the generated xml seems matching your schema (assuming that com prefix is resolved to httpAddress/common) so your hardcoded xml is 'wrong'.

Normally, the namespace for the ValuationDetail class can be declared either in is XMLRoot or XMLType annotation of that class, or on the XMLElement of enclosing Valuation object.

But it seems that you have mistake in your xsd schema that you used to generated the beans as it does not matches your 'hardcoded' xml.